# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'D.MARCA' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
UPDATE altas_moto_diaria D
JOIN cuotas_teoricas C ON D.MARCA = C.MARCA
SET D.GPO = C.GRUPO, D.XDAMA = C.DAMA, D.XB_DAMA = C.BASE_DAMA, D.XROTO = C.ROTO, D.XB_ROTO = C.BASE_ROTO;
```

y me dice que

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'D.MARCA' in 'on clause'

Comment: Trata eliminando los alias y especificando el nombre entero de las tablas

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que altas_moto_diaria contiene la columna MARCA? Lo mismo se te ha ido el dedo y has cambiado el nombre al escribir.

Comment: Prueba agregando el FROM a la tabla `altas_mot_diaria`, para que quede algo así: `UPDATE altas_moto_diaria
       SET D.GPO = C.GRUPO, 
       D.XDAMA = C.DAMA, 
       D.XB_DAMA = C.BASE_DAMA, 
       D.XROTO = C.ROTO, 
       D.XB_ROTO = C.BASE_ROTO
       FROM   altas_moto_diaria D
       JOIN cuotas_teoricas C 
            ON D.MARCA = C.MARCA`

Answer (score 0):

Sin conocer las estructuras de sus tablas es complicado determinar la causa del problema, pero parece ser un tema en la definición de las columnas.

Con las siguientes estructuras de tablas su sentencia funcionaría:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
  `altas_moto_diaria`,
  `cuotas_teoricas`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cuotas_teoricas` (
  `MARCA` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `GRUPO` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `DAMA` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `BASE_DAMA` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `ROTO` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `BASE_ROTO` BIGINT UNSIGNED
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `altas_moto_diaria` (
  `MARCA` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `GPO` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `XDAMA` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `XB_DAMA` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `XROTO` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  `XB_ROTO` BIGINT UNSIGNED
);
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3a969f05f71f6391865587e567b3a0e).